# Multiple insert problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba, syntax

I am doing a multiple insert in vba access query as below:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Enter()
DoCmd.RunSQL ("insert into tblAutonumber (Dummy)values ('DummyValue')")
Dim lastAutonumber As Long
lastAutonumber = DMax("Autonumber", "tblAutonumber")
txtAutoNumber.Value = lastAutonumber
DoCmd.RunSQL ("insert into tbltesting " & _ 
    "(Empid, TestScenario, testid, owner, event, version, " & _ 
    "expresult, variation, status, homestore) values ('" & _
        Me.txtEmpNo.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtTestScenario.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtAutoNumber.Value & " ' ,'" & _
        Me.txtOwner.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtEvent.Value & "', '" & _
        Me.txtVersion.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtExpectedResult.Value & "', '" & _
        Me.txtVariation.Value & "', '" & _
        Me.txtStatus.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtHomeStore.Value & "')")

DoCmd.RunSQL ("insert into tblContract " & _ 
    "(Empid, testid, Day, Start1, Finish1, Store1," & _ 
    "Start2, Finish2, Store2 ) values ('" & _
        Me.txtEmpNo.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtAutoNumber.Value & "','Sunday ','" & _
        Me.txtContSunStart1.Value & "', '" & _
        Me.txtContSunFinish1.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContSunStore1.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContSunStart2.Value & "', '" & _
        Me.txtContSunFinish2.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContSunStore2.Value & "')")

DoCmd.RunSQL ("insert into tblContract " & _ 
    "(Empid, testid, Day, Start1, Finish1, Store1, " & _ 
    "Start2, Finish2, Store2 ) values ('" & _
        Me.txtEmpNo.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtAutoNumber.Value & "','Monday ','" & _
        Me.txtContMonStart1.Value & "', '" & _
        Me.txtContMonFinish1.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContMonStore1.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContMonStart2.Value & "', '" & _
        Me.txtContMonFinish2.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContMonStore2.Value & "')")

DoCmd.RunSQL ("insert into tblContract " & _ 
    "(Empid, testid, Day, Start1, Finish1, Store1," & _ 
    "Start2, Finish2, Store2 ) values ('" & _
        Me.txtEmpNo.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtAutoNumber.Value & "','Tuesday','" & _
        Me.txtContTueStart1.Value & "', '" & _
        Me.txtContTueFinish1.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContTueStore1.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContTueStart2.Value & "', '" & _
        Me.txtContTueFinish2.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContTueStore2.Value & "')")

DoCmd.RunSQL ("insert into tblContract " & _ 
    "(Empid, testid, Day, Start1, Finish1, Store1, " & _ 
    "Start2, Finish2, Store2 ) values ('" & _
        Me.txtEmpNo.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtAutoNumber.Value & "','Wednesday','" & _
        Me.txtContWedStart1.Value & "', '" & _
        Me.txtContWedFinish1.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContWedStore1.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContWedStart2.Value & "', '" & _
        Me.txtContWedFinish2.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContWedStore2.Value & "')")

DoCmd.RunSQL ("insert into tblContract " & _ 
    "(Empid, testid, Day, Start1, Finish1, Store1," & _ 
    "Start2, Finish2, Store2 ) values ('" & _
        Me.txtEmpNo.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtAutoNumber.Value & "','Thursday','" & _
        Me.txtContThuStart1.Value & "', '" & _
        Me.txtContThuFinish1.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContThuStore1.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContThuStart2.Value & "', '" & _
        Me.txtContThuFinish2.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContThuStore2.Value & "')")

DoCmd.RunSQL ("insert into tblContract " & _ 
    "(Empid, testid, Day, Start1, Finish1, Store1," & _ 
    "Start2, Finish2, Store2 )values ('" & _
        Me.txtEmpNo.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtAutoNumber.Value & "','Friday','" & _
        Me.txtContFriStart1.Value & "', '" & _
        Me.txtContFriFinish1.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContFriStore1.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContFriStart2.Value & "', '" & _
        Me.txtContFriFinsh2.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContFriStore2.Value & "')")

DoCmd.RunSQL ("insert into tblContract " & _ 
    "(Empid, testid, Day, Start1, Finish1, Store1," & _ 
    "Start2, Finish2, Store2 )values ('" & _
        Me.txtEmpNo.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtAutoNumber.Value & "','Saturday','" & _
        Me.txtContSatStart1.Value & "', '" & _
        Me.txtContSatFinish1.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContSatiStore1.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContSatStart2.Value & "', '" & _
        Me.txtContSatFinish2.Value & "','" & _
        Me.txtContSatStore2.Value & "')")

End Sub
```

First two queries works fine (i.e. till Sunday)

But from Monday the execution breaks

I checked all variable in the query , there is not nulls there

Comment: When i execute ; it will insert two row into two tables then it will say "microsoft access cant append all record in access query"

Comment: it break by going to the code window and i can see a yellow line with an yellow arrow

Comment: Adding a new question when you still didn't answer the question on the old one about what ERROR message are you getting, isn't going to get you an answer any faster. We can't tell why it is happening because YOU aren't giving us the info we need.

Comment: Your Friday and Saturday lines both have some apparent typos in them: txtContFriFinsh2 is missing an i, txtContSatiStore1 has an extra i, unless those are your actual form field names. But this is after where you say the error occurs, so something else is going on too.

Comment: there is not typo i put the curson on each variable and i can see the value of each variable in the query; 

even there are no NULL  also

Comment: Empid,testid,Day,Start1,Finish1,Store1,Start2,Finish2,Store2 -- what are the data types, integrity constraints, test data, ...?

Comment: So your form field names are really txtContFriFinsh2 and txtContSatiStore1 unlike their counterparts? You should build your query up as a separate string for a single day with just a couple fields so you can show it in the debug window, and get it working at the simplest level. Then add more fields one by one until they all work or you identify the problem. Then replicate the query for the remaining days.

Comment: And what primary key and unique constraints exist on tblContract?

Comment: its was the problem with primary key of testid when i removed it works fine

Comment: So the short story is you were trying to reuse the same key (an auto-number that you are generating) for each insert, on a column that has a unique constraint. This is what the Autonumber datatype is meant to avoid. You shouldn't be creating them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

print your concatenations out, I'll bet you can see your error then...

Comment: there is not typo i put the curson on each variable and i can see the value of each variable in the query; even there are no NULL also

Comment: strange errors usually prove your assumptions wrong.  try changing the order of the inserts, put "Friday" before "Sunday".

Answer (score 1):

If your query "breaks" by going to the code window with the yellow line and arrow but does not give you any error message then it is a good symptom that the compiled code is somewhat corrupted.

If this is your symptom then a decompile & recompile would probably correct your problem.

You can decompile by adding the switch /decompile when you call Access with your database.

```
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft office\office\msaccess.exe" 
                                  /decompile "c:\My Documents\MyDatabase.mdb"
```

And recompile by going to the code windows within Access and using the menu Debug->Compile...

Answer (score 0):

Without knowning more about how the program "breaks" my guess is that one of the values for Monday contains characters that SQL Server is interpreting as syntactic elements. In otherwords you are injecting unescaped strings into the query string. (Incidentally, this is the cause of SQL Injection Attacks). If possible, you should prefer parameters over building up querys like this.

Answer (score 0):

As expressed above by Colin Mackay, your specific problem is likely to be an invalid query in the bunch.

Clear it up by...Making it visible and repeatable..and then offload the diagnostics to msaccess by ....

Building your queries in a variable so that you may easily dump them out...

You will encounter the problem:

1. Dump out the query text ...(cntrl-g, then type ? *sqltxt* )
2. Use access itself to diagnose.  Do this by simply copying  the querytext into a new query (sql view) and either switching  to design mode or attempting to run the query... Access will complain and usually give you enough of a hint to fix the query...

For the future consider adding appropriate error handling for each query.

Also consider using currentdb.execute instead of docmd, because, for the latter, you may have to take the additional step of suppressing confirmation boxes (as per my foggy memory of msaccess2k)

Also *dlookup* and *dmax* (+1) on the current are handy function for getting a unique key without having to resort to an autonumber. I only say this because it appears you are using a table to generate keys...

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

While you are in break mode, press Ctl+G to open the debug window, and type:

```
? txtContTueStart1, txtContTueFinish1
```

etc..to make sure those values are ok.